# Best practice designing REST API to get and send multiple files with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a requirement to have a service for many files on my request (uploading) and many files on my response (downloading).

Something like that:

```
@PostMapping("upload")
public MultipartFile uploadFiles(MultipartFile[] files) {}

@PostMapping("download")
public MultipartFile[] uploadFiles(MultipartFile file) {}
```

I need the filename, content-type and ByteStream for every "attachment".
Zipping is no solution.

I want to do that with the Spring framework. But it is possible to use other frameworks.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: For example, I know how to do that.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Please try and post your code with a specific problem if you don't succeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    storageService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}
```